# Getting value as undefined when trying to retrieve from Observable

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an `Observable` declared as `data$` in which I could see the values (array of objects) in the console. But when I try to subscribe and get the value from `data$`, it returns `undefined`. Here is my code:

`data$ = this.feedValue.feedValues$; \\This returns some values as array of objects.Could see the values under actionObserver`

I am trying to get the values inside this observable by doing this,
`dataResponse: any;`

`this.data$.subscribe(resp => (this.dataResponse = resp));`

`dataResponse` is shown as `undefined`.

Comment: Can you please provide more details about the issue or a working demo?

Comment: data$ return values as  [
    { "date": "2020-01-02", "open": 10.3, "close": 10.29},
    { "date": "2020-01-03", "open": 10.29, "close": 10.31},
    { "date": "2020-01-06", "open": 10.22, "close": 10.21},
    { "date": "2020-01-07", "open": 10.12, "close": 10.1}
  ]; under action observer. I am trying to subscribe to this observable and get these vales. It throws undefined. I am doing this inside a method when a button is pressed in html.

Comment: Not about the values.Where does values will be emitted to the Observable, so that values will be retrieved inside the subscription callback. Also it will be better if you have some working demo of the issue at StackBlitz :)